# Geofence Testing on Devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, geofencing, worklight-geolocation

I'm new to IBM Worklight and understand that Worklight has Geofencing capabilities and testing within the mobile simulator. Does Worklight have some way to test geofencing on actual devices, while still anaylzing location/wifi data?

Answer (score 1):

For testing on actual devices, beyond physically moving the devices, you would have to use simulation tools available outside of IBM Worklight. For example, for iOS this would be in XCode and for Android you could either utilize a location simulation app, or embed mock locations yourself (see [location testing](https://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html) on the Android development site).

Additionally, if you want more comprehensive testing, which includes the ability to simulate GPS as part of your tests, you may want to check out IBM Rational Test Workbench.